# How Can I Plot Specific Rows from Excel File in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I have an Excel file that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to plot all 3 individuals' weight on Jan 1, 2020 on a bar chart to compare visually in Python using Matplotlib. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Desktop\\file.csv', index_col = 'Date', 
parse_dates = True)  #importing data to python and making date column as 
index
df['year'] = df.index.year #extracting year from index
data_20 = df[df['year'] == 2020] # Filtering out 2020 date
ax = data_20.plot(kind='bar',x='Name',y='Weight') #Plotting by name for 2020
```

To plot only for 2 people:

```
ax = data_20[data_20['Name'] != 'John Smith']
.plot(kind='bar',x='Name',y='Weight') #Plotting by name for 2020
ax.set_ylabel('Weights in lbs') #Labeling y-axis
ax.set_xlabel('Names') #Labeling x-axis
ax.set_title('Weights for 2020') # Adding the title
```

To make it pretty just add labels:

```
ax.set_ylabel('Weights in lbs') #Labeling y-axis
ax.set_xlabel('Names') #Labeling x-axis
ax.set_title('Weights for 2020'); # Adding the title
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm still experimenting with it. Would you know how I can plot just two people (ex: Tom Berry and Peter James)?

Comment: You can filter out the same way: Just use data_20[data_20['Name'] != 'John Smith'].

Comment: Thank you, that works but what if I have say 5 names in Excel and I want to plot only 2 names? I used the following code: data_20 = data_20[data_20['Name']== ['John Smith', 'Peter James']] but it is giving my a "Lengths must match to compare" error. Thank you

Comment: data_20[(data_20['Name'] == 'John Smith') | (data_20['Name'] == 'Peter James')].plot(kind='bar',x='Name',y='Weight')

Answer (score 1):

It's probably easiest done with pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt


df = pd.read_excel('your_file_location', sheet_name='sheet_name', parse_dates=['Date'])
df = df.loc[df['Date'] == dt.date(year=2020, month=1, day=1)]
ax = df.plot.bar(df['Name'], df['Weight'])
```

Here we first load data from a specific sheet of your excel file (you can omit `sheet_name` argument if your excel file has only a single sheet), then we filter data to show only records from a specific date and then plot with names on x-axis and weight on y-axis.

Comment: Thank you, I'm still experimenting with it. Would you know how I can plot just two people (ex: Tom Berry and Peter James)?